# Title lines with border-left

Tags: css

I have this blog title which usually occupies more than 1 line.

I would like that each line have a left border with 5px, like the following example:

[image]

Comment: Sounds reasonable. What's your question? What is the HTML and CSS you have now, what is it doing, and what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please make sure to add sample code or JSFiddle/Codepen link while posting a question. Otherwise, the question looks too abstract to answer.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your replies, but it sounds like someone else got the idea from the layout image I've produced and helped me with box-decoration-break which I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 2):

The `box-decoration-break` property is what you are in search of. You may need to use browser prefixes based on browsers you are supporting. For Chrome and Edge, we'll need `-webkit-box-decoration-break`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2j96potm/3/)

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

div {
  width: 350px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 5px;
}

span {
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  background: white;
  border-left: 4px solid orange;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Fusce vehicula enim. Sed libero justo lorem, morbi, commodo labore litora</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel.
It's exactly what I would need.